# Why can't I write 2 variables at the same time to a file in Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
def yaml_processor(period):
    filepath_reg = "../public/log/testing.log.yaml"
    data = yaml_loader(filepath)
    data = data.get(period)
    for team, key in data.iteritems():
        file = open("test.log.yaml", 'w')
        file.write('%team %period\n')
        file.close()
        print(team, period)
```

It doesn't want to write them `file.write('{team}, {period}\n')`, but prints the values perfectly ...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are truncating the file when you open it in write mode. Either open in append mode (`'a'`), or better yet, open it *before* the loop and and leave it open until after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec).

Try replacing `file.write('%team %period\n')` with

```
file.write('{} {}\n'.format(team, period))
```

Comment: @ivand58 Thanks! Missed that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a recent version of Python (3.6 or later), you can take advantage of [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/):

```
with open("test.log.yaml", 'w') as file:
    file.write(f'{team} {period}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file in each iteration of the loop which removes the previous values. Just move the open and close statement out of the loop.

```
def yaml_processor(period):
filepath_reg = "../public/log/testing.log.yaml"
data = yaml_loader(filepath)
data = data.get(period)
file = open("test.log.yaml", 'w')
for team, key in data.iteritems():
    file.write('%team %period\n')
    print(team, period)
file.close()
```